# how can i remove data from my table view on a button click?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

how can i remove datas from my table vie on a button click.
 i added 5 images in to my table view .next time i am adding only 3 images but the last 4 and 5 images will not remove from my table view . can any one provide me a good way to do it.

my code is

```
 (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


 static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

 UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
 if (cell == nil) {
  cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
 }


      if(indexPath.row == 0)
      {
       UIImageView *imageView1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,5,100,125)];

       if([imageArray count]>0)
       {
       imageView1.image = [imageArray objectAtIndex:0];
       [cell.contentView addSubview:imageView1];
       [imageView1 release];
       }
       if([imageArray count]>1)
       {
       UIImageView *imageView2 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(150,5,100,125)];
       imageView2.image = [imageArray objectAtIndex:1];
       [cell.contentView addSubview:imageView2];
       [imageView2 release];
       }
       if([imageArray count]>2)
       {
       UIImageView *imageView3 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(310, 5, 100, 125)];
       imageView3.image = [imageArray objectAtIndex:2];
       [cell.contentView addSubview:imageView3];
       [imageView3 release];
       }
       if([imageArray count]>3)
       {
       UIImageView *imageView4 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(460,5,100,125)];
       imageView4.image = [imageArray objectAtIndex:3];
       [cell.contentView addSubview:imageView4];
       [imageView4 release];
       }

      }
      else if(indexPath.row == 1)
      {
       if([imageArray count]>4)
       {
       UIImageView *imageView5 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,5,100,125)];
       imageView5.image = [imageArray objectAtIndex:4];
       [cell.contentView addSubview:imageView5];
       [imageView5 release];
       }
       if([imageArray count]>5)
       {       
       UIImageView *imageView6 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(150,5,100,125)];
       imageView6.image = [imageArray objectAtIndex:5];
       [cell.contentView addSubview:imageView6];
       [imageView6 release];
       }

       if([imageArray count]>6)
       {
       UIImageView *imageView7= [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(310, 5, 100, 125)];
       imageView7.image = [imageArray objectAtIndex:6];
       [cell.contentView addSubview:imageView7];
       [imageView7 release];
       }
```

and on a  button click i am removing all object from my array. and adding only 3 images to it.
then calling myTableView.reloadData();

but the first three is changing and remaining 4 & 5 are still there not removing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a hunch, but you might want to check your implementation of tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:

Please post that if you're still having trouble.

Comment: numberOfSectionsInTableView is 1

Comment: You are adding images 0 to 3 (first 4 images) in first row. And 4th image in second row. And we are getting impression that there are total 5 rows. The images appears one below other as separate cells due to their frame assigned one below the other. Basically, the images are not at all getting added in separate rows.

Comment: and your removing the items from imageArray, not just setting the values to nil? And then calling reloadData after that, correct?

Comment: @christina, your table's objective is to show the images in different cells, right?

Comment: looking at your code, i should say, add the images in different cells (right now image 0 to 3 are getting added in row 0 and image 4 in row 1, assuming there are total 5 images), and then it shall work the way you are doing.